# Button does nothing in PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, sockets, user-interface, port, pysimplegui

I made a port scanner today and the GUI is very unpolished for now, but when testing it I noticed that when pressing "Scan ports" it does nothing.

I cant find anything obvious in my code. What did I miss?

```py
import socket
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def scan_ports(target_ip, start_port, end_port):
    print(f"Scanning ports on {target_ip}...")
    for port in range(start_port, end_port + 1):
        try:
            sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            socket.setdefaulttimeout(1)
            result = sock.connect_ex((target_ip, port))
            if result == 0:
                print(f"Port {port} is open")
            sock.close()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("Scan interrupted by user.")
            break
        except socket.error:
            print("Couldn't connect to server.")
            break


def port_scan_window():
    layoutport = [
        [sg.Text("            IP:          Starting port:     Ending port:")],
        [sg.Button("Scan ports", key="-SCAN-"), sg.Input(key="-PORTIP-"), sg.Input(key="-START-"), sg.Input(key="-END-")],
        [sg.Output(size=(30,20))],
        [sg.Button("Exit")]
    ]

    port_window = sg.Window('Port scanner', layoutport)

    while True:
        event, values = port_window.Read()
        if event in (None, "Scan ports"):
            print("Scanning " + values["-PORTIP-"] + " for Open ports")
            scan_ports(target_ip=values["-PORTIP-"], start_port=values["-START-"], end_port=values["-END-"])
        elif event in (None, "Exit"):
            break
    
    port_window.Close()

port_scan_window()
```

Comment: Perhaps none of the ports are open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `event` is `-SCAN-` as you defined it in `sg.Button("Scan ports", key="-SCAN-")`.

So this should work:

```
if event in (None, "-SCAN-"):
```

The event would have been `Scan ports` if you hadn't used `key`:

```
sg.Button("Scan ports")
```

or if you had set `key` to `'Scan ports'` :

```
sg.Button("Scan ports", key='Scan ports')
```

---

In addition, the `event` is `None` when you close the window. So you are calling `scan_ports` when the `X` button is pressed.

You might want to use:

```
if event == "-SCAN-":
```

or

```
 if event == "Scan ports":
```

instead.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. The program now just crashes after pressing it but it does register now XD